# Integral of complex function with exponential

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

Given $r>0, t\in [0,2 \pi],m\in \mathbb{Z}$ I want to find the integral for

$$
\int_0^{2 \pi} e^{i(m+1)t}
$$

Now I have the problem that I found two such integrals
$$
\int e^{i(m+1)t}=\frac{e^{i(m+1)t}}{i(m+1)}
$$
but also
$$
\int e^{i(m+1)t}=-\frac{ie^{i(m+1)t}}{(m+1)}
$$
So one of them has definitely to be wrong... where is my mistake?

Comment: $1/i=-i$, the result is the same.

Comment: Thank you @Jon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This integral is well-known, one has
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i(m+1)t}dt=\left.\frac{e^{i(m+1)t}}{i(m+1)}\right|_0^{2\pi}.
$$
Now, assuming $m$ an integer, this yields
$$
\frac{e^{i(m+1)2\pi}-1}{i(m+1)}=0 {\ m\ne -1}
$$
otherwise its value is 1.